# CSS HTML Only Grey Rectangle with faded color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the following GREY (really want these shades of grey) image out of CSS & HTML Only:

[image]

You can see how the grep color is stronger at the bottom and more faded at the top and middle.

Here is a link to the image:
http://www.content.dating/online-dating/dating-website/navigation-background.png

Here is a fiddle where I've been attempting:

http://jsfiddle.net/m0hbty67/3/

Currently the color is wrong and the fade is going in the wrong direction - still trying.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thankyou

Base Code:

```
<div id="navBackGround"></div>

#navBackGround {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 160px;
    height: 690px;

    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect grey if you use `rgba(255,0,0,0)` and `rgba(255,0,0,1)` (i.e. from transparent red to opaque red)?

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#f3f3f4+0,f3f3f4+71,dfe0e1+87,d3d4d6+100;Custom  Import from image - great feature. :)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m0hbty67/5/ give or take

Comment: Don't lie, you aren't trying :-D you are writting a gradient with right direction and with red color. I think that you are copy&pasting without read your own code. You can use tools like the answers said, but it's better if you read the code and you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pLpeak5g/)

```
background: rgb(243,243,244); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,244,1) 0%, rgba(213,214,215,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(243,243,244,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(213,214,215,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,244,1) 0%,rgba(213,214,215,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,244,1) 0%,rgba(213,214,215,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(243,243,244,1) 0%,rgba(213,214,215,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(243,243,244,1) 0%,rgba(213,214,215,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f3f4', endColorstr='#d5d6d7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```